# How to set similar constraints on multiple variables in Solve

Tags: syntax

In this equation:

```
var = {x, y, z, m};
Solve[x + 2y + z + m == 14 && And @@ Thread[2 <= var <= 3], var, Integers]
```

> {{x->2,y->3,z->3,m->3},{x->3,y->3,z->2,m->3},{x->3,y->3,z->3,m->2}}

But I think `...And @@ Thread[2 <= var <= 3]...Integers` is very ugly. So I give this another try as follows:

```
var = {x, y, z, m};
Solve[x + 2y + z + m == 14 && (Alternatives@@ var == (2|3)), var]
```

But I get some error information.

I would like to know whether there are better methods to do do this.

Comment: How about `Solve[x+2y+z+m==14&&2<=var<=3,var,Integers]`?

Comment: @Jens Do you know in which version that first worked?  It does in 10.1 but not in 7.0.

Comment: Thanks @Jens ,I think your comment make this problem be more simple.If you post it as an answer,I'll accept it.:)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just checked version 9 and it doesn't work there either. So it must be new in version 10...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 10, you can use this simpler syntax without `Thread`:

```
Solve[x+2y+z+m==14&&2<=var<=3,var,Integers]
```

> `{{x->2,y->3,z->3,m->3},{x->3,y->3,z->2,m->3},{x->3,y->3,z->3,m->2}}`

Comment: The syntax does out of my expectation.Congratulations on your exploration.

Comment: Can you help me check `var={x,y,z,m};Minimize[{x+2y+z+m,2<=var<=3},var]` in your version 9?

Comment: @yode I checked and it doesn't work in ver. 9. I again had to use `var = {x, y, z, m}; Minimize[{x + 2 y + z + m, 
  And @@ Thread[2 <= var <= 3]}, var]`

Comment: The `And` is necessary?

Comment: No, (in version 9) I can leave out the `And` (just copied it from your post). The main issue seems to be that `Thread` isn't done automatically.