# How to get the long logic expression with a terse method

Tags: syntax, expression-manipulation

I have a long logic expression

```
(x==2||x==3||x==4)&&(y==2||y==3||y==4)&&(z==2||z==3||z==4)&&(m==2||m==3||m==4)
```

How to get it by a terse express?
This is current method

```
Or@@@(Thread[#=={2,3,4}]&/@And[x,y,z,m])
```

> (x==2||x==3||x==4)&&(y==2||y==3||y==4)&&(z==2||z==3||z==4)&&(m==2||m==3||m==4)

But I'm very dissatisfy that `/@` and that `()`.I think there must are terse method can do this.Anybody can give a try?

Comment: Your equations vary in time ...

Comment: @yarchik I'm very sorry for the serious typo.But everyone have that time.:)

Comment: Am I missing something? Is the construct that you have some set of variables, and you want to test if all of them are contained in some set of values? If so, then `ConstainsAll[values,vars]` will suffice, and for really big examples (I'm assuming since the example is not really long, it's just an example) it will be *vastly* faster (as in thousands of times for big cases) than solutions so far...

Comment: @ciao Thanks for your concern this post.The question drived from [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112234/how-to-set-similar-constraints-on-multiple-variables-in-solve).My solution is `var={x,y,z,m};
Solve[x+2y+z+m==24&&(x==2||x==7||x==4)&&(y==2||y==7||y==4)&&(z==2||z==7||z==4)&&(m==2||m==7||m==4),var]`.So I want to get `(x==2||x==7||x==4)&&(y==2||y==7||y==4)&&(z==2||z==7||z==4)&&(m==2||m==7||m==4)` by a concise code.

Comment: @yode : ah, well for the referenced post (the goal of this question I take it?), seems to me `Solve[x + 2 y + z + m == 14 && 
  And @@ Thread[2 <= {x, y, z, m} <= 4], Integers]` is pretty concise...

Comment: @ciao When the integer is 2, 4, 7 or more scatter digtal, your method will 
be mess maybe.But this method can be `var={x,y,z,m};Solve[x+2y+z+m==24&&And@@Or@@@Outer[Equal,{x,y,z,m},{2,4,7}],var]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My offering:

```
And @@ Or @@@ Outer[Equal, {x, y, z, m}, {2, 3, 4}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've swapped the logical functions around to your new requirements.

Comment: I think `Distribute[Equal[And[x,y,z,m],Or[2,3,4]],And]` should have a same output.But actually not.

Comment: I see what you mean, it doesn't quite work does it! If it did `And @@ Thread[{x, y, z} == Or[2, 3, 4]]` would be a fraction terser

Answer (score 1):

A set solution.

```
cond = {{x}, {y}, {z}, {m}} ∈ Interval[{2, 4}] && {x, y, z, m} ∈ Integers
```

Set `x`, `y`, `z`, and `m` to be `Integers` on the `Interval` 2 to 4.  We can use `cond` to be certain it is defined as expected.

```
Solve[x + y + z + m == 8 && cond, {x, y, z, m}]
(* {{x -> 2, y -> 2, z -> 2, m -> 2}} *)
```

This gives the expected result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
And @@ Thread@Table[Or @@ Thread@Table[j == i, {i, {2, 3, 4}}], {j, {x, y, z, m}}]
```

Comment: With just one `Table`: `And @@ Or @@@ Table[j == i, {j, {x, y, z, m}}, {i, {2, 3, 4}}]`

Comment: yes that's much better. I now realize that the my `Table` is essentially doing what your `Outer` does. But your solution is so much prettier!